# NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties vs. WMI for Ipaddresses, dns-servers, dhcp etc

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

Should I prefer one over the other?

Im leaning heavily towards `NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties` instead of `select * from win32_networkAdapterConfiguration` from WMI if I can verify that all the information I need is available

Comment: Looks like same stuff, do you get different values, or are you concerned about the speed?

Comment: Mostly if anyone could say: "you dont get XYZ in WMI/NetworkInfo" or WMI/NetworkInfo is much more unstable/slow/someother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NetworkInformation` if you can and if it can provide everything you want. WMI is a much more generic interface that implements all sorts of things, and is a service that can be stopped or might not be available or even corrupted (it has happened to me a few times). `NetworkInformation` I believe is a wrapper around the Win32 APIs so it should almost always work and have no dependencies (besides .NET 3.0+).

Always better to use the simplest and more specific tool that gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know WMI is much slower